# IOS 8 set view frame not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a view which i want to shift its position when keyboard is shown, i use **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** delegate to update the position, and its working perfectly in IOS 7 device but when i try to run it **in IOS 8 device, then view is not repositioned** , the frame is updated as i can see it in log.

following is my code

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*) notification{

    @autoreleasepool {
        CGRect frame = _loginFrame.frame;
        frame.origin.y-=200;

        DLog(@"login frame %@ ",NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [_loginFrame setFrame:frame];
        }];
    }
```

}

But, when i try the animation in dispatch_after block its animating to the new position

```
   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [_loginFrame setFrame:frame];
    }];
});
```

any idea why the frame is not animating to the new position without dispatch_after ?

Thanks!

NOTE: **it looks like the setFrame: method is not working** , dont know why, i have created a basic ios 8 application to test this

> 2014-09-11 18:59:54.836 KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974] keyboard show
>   2014-09-11 18:59:54.837 KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974]  **old frame
>   {{60, 269}, {200, 30}}**  2014-09-11 18:59:54.837
>   KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974]  **update frame {{60, 169}, {200, 30}}** 
>   2014-09-11 18:59:55.339 KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974]  **completion
>   block frame {{60, 269}, {200, 30}}**  2014-09-11 18:59:55.822
>   KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974] keyboard hide 2014-09-11 18:59:55.822
>   KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974]  **old frame {{60, 269}, {200, 30}}** 
>   2014-09-11 18:59:56.324 KeyboardCheck[31215:1451974]  **completion
>   block frame {{60, 269}, {200, 30}}**

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: If `dispatch_after` works, most caused by you using auto layout. The right way to do this is updating your constraints instead of setting frame.

Comment: Yes Am using autolayout, but i haven't had this issue in IOS 7, the constraint is set for left , right , bottom spacing

Comment: Same problem here, the frame is updated but the view is not redrawn

Comment: I have a similar problem; animation works perfectly in iOS 7, but in iOS 8 the animation happens, but at the end it jumps back to the original position.

Comment: Re my comment above: In iOS Simulator; I'll try it on iPhone 6 when it arrives (keeping iPhone 5 at iOS 7 for now).

Comment: thanks for your comment, am also doing the same for now

Comment: I tried it on iOS 8 iPad; the same code that works in iOS 7 is indeed failing. The animation moves about halfway to the target and then jumps back to the starting point.  I can add the animation (theView.center = newCentre) to the completion block to get to the proper final location, but it's ugly.  iOS 7 does it perfectly and smoothly. Does anyone else have an animation problem in iOS 8 that is fine in 7? Maybe it accidentally worked in 7 and 8 tightened some requirement.

Comment: My code:

 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:(0)
                     animations:^ { theView.center = newCentre; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         NSLog( @"animatePickerView animation finished %d, y %f", finished, theView.center.y);

In 7.1 theView.center.y printed is the new value, in 8.0 it's the old value. Does this smell like an 8.0 bug?

Comment: If you use auto layout then, Only you need to add _loginFrame .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; , it will work :).

Comment: Thanks @Aju, you have saved me from my hours of struggling with this

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by unchecking Use Auto Layout.

If you want Auto Layout, here is another possible solution:

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/animating-views-does-not-seem-to-work-in-ios8-but-did-in-ios7